# explorer bar - embedding a webbrowser into it

Tags: internet-explorer, com, ole, embedding

For the purpose of navigating that left horizontal / vertical explorer bar to various web pages. 
[Explorer bar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144099%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
Does this seem feasible ?

This has been asked before, but did not get an answer (second part of [IE "per browser" explorer bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106033/ie-per-browser-explorer-bar))

Thanks

Comment: `Does this seem feasible?` I've done this. A long time ago though, back in the days of IE6.

Comment: Wow! Igor Tandetnik! This name brings me back memories :) Was it hard or pretty straightforward ActiveX mingling ? And does it still run OK in more recent IE versions ?

Comment: I recall it being fairly straightforward. The only somewhat tricky thing was getting keyboard navigation work (tabbing around, Ctrl+C / Ctrl+V) - you do this by carefully implementing `IInputObject`. However, IE6 didn't have tabs - those might complicate things. As to whether my application runs on later IE versions - I have no idea. I left the company, it collapsed shortly thereafter, the product doesn't exist anymore, and I don't have the source code for it.